# Problema al dividir una suma

Tags: c

Mi código es el siguiente:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int v;

    long long dias[v];

    long long suma=0;
    
    scanf("%d",&v);
    for( int  i = 0; i < v; i++ ) {
        
        scanf("%Ld",&dias[i]);   
        suma += dias[i];
    }
 

    suma = suma/365;
    
    printf("%Ld",suma);
    
  
        return 0;
}
```

Lo que quiero lograr con este código es pedir un numero para saber de que dimensión será el arreglo, a partir de ahí llenar el arreglo (se llenaran con números muy grandes ≤ 250000), después sumarlos y el resultado dividirlo entre 365.
El problema es que si el arreglo es de 4 o mas números, me arroja un numero muy grande y no se por que hace eso.
Espero que me puedan explicar como darle solución.

Comment: declaras un `int` sin un valor y luego a tu array le asignas ese `int` (sin valor), debes de reservar la memoria cuando ya tengas el valor. Tu array `dias` también esta vacío y lo recorres sin asignarle un valor, si lo imprimes cuando no tiene valor te devolverá basura

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ya pude hacer que funcionara correctamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Veo el tag de C++. Si estas en C++ deverias estar utilizando `std::vector`. Pero tu codigo parece mas C. Si estas en C deverias investigar sobre `malloc` y `free`.

Answer (score 1):

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) las formaciones<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática<sup>2</sup> tienen que tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. Para tu formación `dias` estás usando como tamaño una variable (`v`) cuyo valor sólo se conocerá en tiempo de ejecución.

Peor aún, defines la formación antes de que hayas decidido el valor de `v` ¿acaso esperas que las lecturas sobre `v` causen cambios retroactivos?:

```
int v;             // 'v' tiene un valor indeterminado
long long dias[v]; // Se usa 'v' para definir 'dias', la longitud de 'dias' es indeterminada
...
scanf("%d",&v); // Ahora se lee 'v', pese a que ya se ha usado antes.
```

Lo que en realidad necesitas hacer es esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int v;
    scanf("%d", &v); // Leemos el valor de 'v' antes de usarla

    // Creamos memoria dinámica en base al valor leído en 'v'
    long long *dias = (long long *)malloc(v * sizeof(long long));

    long long suma = 0;

    for (int  i = 0; i < v; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%Ld",&dias[i]);   
        suma += dias[i];
    }

    printf("%Ld", suma / 365);

    // Liberamos la memoria dinámica solicitada.
    free(dias);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7bTsMwDIav66ewhkDJyiFjB0DdeALeAHER0nRESpMpaXsB2rMXu5y5@BL5t/37NxfG67AfxxMXjO9ri9vc1S5evtzDH8m7Z9bAhQ5b7YKQ8AYFV0MFRTY6NGJ2Ws/OzwZZARQ@hj1Oz7x2OuMOxS9Jttr7aMSAc8zu1cbmpyv/7ee@1bSuWG1iQsFH0U0SfVsKgGXpJBQU6DvJA0fhy4/uSVaIyD12Knf4KVPuI3keEhl@rXxcu8LlZj3FaJK1guepYo9kuz4FDnMcx4WChVJwTSyJFbEmNsQNcUvcqWlGwTs)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

<sup>2</sup>La memoria automática es aquella que no se pide con `malloc`.